# WMI Query - System.Management.ManagementException

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, wmi

I'm getting some errors that I don't really understand. I'm hoping someone can help me.

The first exception I get is `System.Management.ManagementException` on the 'in' in my foreach.

The next is an index out of range on 'device'. What really confuses me is that this worked when it didn't accept variables passed into it. When I re factored it to make it more flexible it broke.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Property and win32Class are passed in from the main program into this class

Here's what and how I'm passing

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GatherSystemINfoWMI.GetPropertyValue("name", "Win32_CDROMDrive");
    }
```

//  Here's what I'm passing it to

```
       public static void GetPropertyValue(string property, string win32Class)
    {

        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
      new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select " + property + "from " + win32Class);
        foreach (ManagementObject device in searcher.Get())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} ",
                          device.GetPropertyValue("Name"));
            Console.WriteLine(device.GetPropertyValue(property) + "\n");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: Not entirely sure about the issue that you're specifically having, but I can see that your string concatenation is incorrect.  Specifically where you have "Select " + property + "from " + win32Class.  Try changing "from " to " from ".  The way you have it now will cause the property to be concatenated directly on to the string literal without a space separating the two.

Comment: The line break there got in the way of what you were going for but I got your meaning. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a space in the *"from "* part of your sql:

Replace

```
"Select " + property + "from " + win32Class
```

with

```
"Select " + property + " from " + win32Class
```

Or better use `string.Format()`:

```
string query = string.Format("Select {0} from {1}", property, win32Class);
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
```